# Edit GVim's Desktop File to Launch with Custom Config

Tags: launcher, gvim, vimrc

I've created a config file for GVim, which located at `$HOME/.config/vim/gvimrc`. And in my `.zshenv` I have `export VIMINIT='let $MYVIMRC="$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/vim/gvimrc" | source $MYVIMRC'`

On running `gvim` from the terminal, the application launches and loads the configuration, but running GVim from the application launcher doesn't load the configuration.

I edited `/usr/share/applications/gvim.desktop` so that the config file specified, and the changes look like:

```
TryExec=gvim -u /home/saurabh/.config/vim/gvimrc
Exec=gvim -u /home/saurabh/.config/vim/gvimrc -f %F
```

but it makes the GVim icon disappear from the application launcher.

The top of the file says:

> The gvim.desktop file is generated by src/po/Makefile, do NOT edit.
> Edit the src/po/gvim.desktop.in file instead.

but I cant find the file `gvim.desktop.in` anywhere.

How can I launch GVim from application launcher so that it loads the custom config?